# Page transition with Slickgrid causes custom editor to disappear

Tags: slickgrid

We use Slickgrid and we have a minor issue when changing to the next page. The editor is active/visible. When the grid is loaded and all data is displayed, we click in e.g. the first row in the grid in order to activate the editor.

When we navigate down in the grid, when we press the down-key on the before-last row, like expected the new page loads data. When the data of the new page is displayed, the editor is not active on the first row, but when we press the down-key the editor becomes active/visible again on row 2.

Then when we press the up-key once, the editor is also active/visible on row 1. It's strange that the editor went off upon page-transition. Also when we press the up-key on the first row of the second page while the editor is visible, the previous page loads, but again the editor is no longer visible (on the last row of that page). But when we press the up-key once again the editor appears again on the before last row (without clicking the mouse).

We tried the normal editor instead of the custom editor but this didn't solve it.

What can be the cause of this or in which event/function etc. we should look? Can it be a missing javascript or css include? Viewport or pager or the data loader?

Comment: Can you post some code or better show this in a fiddle? It's hard to tell what you might be missing..

Comment: It's hard to post code, because we have many views, scripts and helper classes. We use ASP.Net MVC3. Maybe someone else had this same issue and can point us in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

Fortunately the issue has been solved today.

The cause was that we called the SlickGrid function EditActiveCell before the data of the new page was loaded. When this was changed in order that EditActiveCell was called after the loading of the data, the grid behaved like expected.